# "Invalid Icon Path" - Error returned from Apple App Store Team

Tags: ios, app-store, icons

This is my first time submitting something to the App Store, and I am having a lot of issues. First off, let me say that the application has been built with **PhoneGap**, using the **Cordova 1.9.0 framework**. The web application end of it is fine, validates W3, and runs perfectly in browser. I have rebuilt this project from the ground up after being unable to fix the issue manually, but that did not rectify it either. Below is the error that Apple sends back to me...

```
Invalid Icon Path - No icon found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIcons": Default@2x.png
Invalid Icon Path - No icon found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIcons": icon-72@2x.png
Invalid Icon Path - No icon found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIcons": Default.png
```

The only modifications I have made to the icon files was through `Application --> Summary --> App Icons`, using the file selector. I had no errors validating during the submission process, and the icons show up fine on my test phone.

This is, again, my first time doing this. There is a lot of information to post, but I don't know what is required. If you have any ideas it would be very much appreciated, and I will provide any information required for you to help me better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click the plist and select "show raw keys/values". Then delete/edit the value of image icon. Also please verify if there is all the images mentioned in the plist is available in your application else you can delete that entry from plist.

Please find the attached screen shot,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I will try this out and let you know how it goes. :)